# Redis queue run function on last retry

Tags: python, redis, python-rq

I am using the python-rq [`Retry()`](https://python-rq.org/docs/exceptions/) functionality with the [`on_failure`](https://python-rq.org/docs/#job-callbacks) callback. The problem is that the `on_failure` function runs after every failure on the job so it does not allow handling the last retry differently from the previous reties.

In my case I would like to flag my job as failed only if it fails all retries. Is that possible? I am pretty stuck here so I have not tried anything else.

So far I have tried to use the `FailedJobRegistry()` to count the fails of the job but it doesn't seem to support such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by checking in the `on_failure` function that the job has `0` or `None` retries before running the actual `on_failure` logic.

So my my job was enqueued as:

```
job = queue.enqueue(
        _function, 
        job_timeout=timeout,
        retry=Retry(max=5),
        on_failure=report_failure,
    )
```

and the `report_failure()` as:

```
def report_failure(job, connection, type, value, traceback):
    """
    Flag a job as failed if it has 0 or None reties left
    """

    if job.retries_left:
        return

    #...
    # Implement failed on last retry logic
```